# Jpg to PDf in Ghostscript

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ghostscript

Sorry my English. As far as I know, Ghostscript does not support file conversion by mask (*) from the command, and all files must be explicitly listed in command (0001.jpg, 0002.jpg). I came across such a two scripts containing mask conversion, but could not find out the reason why it does not work:

```
@echo off
if %1.==Sub. goto %2
for %%f in (F:\myFOLDER\*.jpg) do call %0 Sub action %%~nf
goto end
:action

"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=F:\myFOLDER\%3.pdf F:\myFOLDER\%3.jpg -c quit

:end
```

```
echo
dir="F:\myFOLDER"
output_file="F:\myFOLDER\out.pdf"
pause

args=""

for file in `find ${dir} -name "*.JPG" -o -name "*.JPEG" -o -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -type f`;
do
  args="${args} (${file}) viewJPEG showpage"
done


"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOSAFER -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=${output_file} "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c ${args}
```

I tried to edit the code using examples from the Internet, but I don't know enough.

Comment: Your first batch *should* work, but is over-complicated. What *does* it do that it should *not* do, and what does it *not* do that it *should* do? What error messages does it produce? Use the `edit` button to included this extra data in your question. The second code is not Windows batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many web snippets that fail to ensure they work for other people that simply cut and paste.

So firstly Ghostscript only accepts pdf as input and jpg as output  not the other way round, UNLESS, you go via Postscript which is accepted as input.

Hence that has limitations like avoid file names that have unsafe characters such as the space character and if you must run a programmable command only do it with known local filenames.

Thus you need to get GhostScript to render and print the .jpg's using a viewer that will briefly flash up screen view (you should not avoid that need) and convert that into PDF

By using NOSAFER it will run Postscript as current user so only run the known script on the safe local files.jpg

```
@echo off
set "GSBIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\bin"
set "FOLDER=F:\myFOLDER"

cd /d "%folder%"
for %%f in (*.jpg) do %GSBIN%\gswin32 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOSAFER -o "%%~nf.pdf" "%GSBIN%\..\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c "(""%%~f"") viewJPEG" -f
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

### NOTE

The above Windows mix as part of both your sources will only allow one jpg per pdf. It is intentionally using Windowed NOT Console **(NOT gswin##C.exe)** version
For Multiple JPG to PDF the sister ArtifeX products GhostPDL or MuTool would be better suited to that task, as they both accept JPG inputs direct.
To produce multipage PDF with above script you would need to write a second line to do merging.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work either when starting by default or when changing variables to explicit paths https://i.imgur.com/SoGFBqz.png

Comment: I have Win7, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Win7 64 // gs10.01.1

Comment: `cd /d "F:\myFOLDER"
for %%f in ("*.jpg") do "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\bin\gswin32c.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOSAFER -o "F:\myFOLDER\okkkkk.pdf" "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.01.1\lib\viewjpeg.ps" -c "(""%%~f"") viewJPEG" -f
cd /d "%~dp0"`

Comment: Right, it's working! I saw the examples online using gswin32c, so I thought there was no difference. But I take it that saving multiple jpg's into one file at once is not supported?

Comment: I tried img2pdf, and I used Ghostscript because it has pdf saving with optimization (`-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` ...)

Comment: Is your zip to cbz development available somewhere?